# I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/uaa/dev/master"

Tags: jhipster

I just started to use jhipster.

I used jhipster to generate a uaa application and I hit the following error when I started it.

I generated this application by using command "yo jhipster" and run it with mvn command.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at me.prince.UaaApp.main(UaaApp.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:483)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/uaa/dev/master": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:498)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:130)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:81)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$BasicAuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:179)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:619)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your registry is either not up or not reachable for your service, if running inside docker

the line telling you what's wrong is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/uaa/dev/master": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

If you start your UAA inside a docker container, make sure you are not accessing "localhost", but "registry" instead

best regards

Comment: Yeah, I didn't start registry.